# Standard Transactions and relaxation rules

Tags: transactions

We all know that there 5 common types of Standard transaction scripts. My question is if we create a script under what rules is it decided if it standard or non-standard?

Under the hypothesis that it is non-standard if some miners accept then what happens? It will be included in a block only if these miners succeed in creating a block?

Furthermore signing transactions without SIGHASH_ALL but with any other hash type is considered non-standard?

Comment: I think some combination of the questions tagged [tag:non-standard] (some of which I have just retagged) address everything you are asking.  You might have a read through those, and then see if you still have something to ask.